# extract date from text and format it as date

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've searched and found some answers but none would match my format.
How to get 22 Jul 2017 13:51 GMT to 22/07/2018 ?
I only need to extract the date in a format that excel will understand so I can sort it from old to new.
Thank you!

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried

Comment: Well I tried format the cell as date, then I tried a few formulas that some did not work, saying if I need to insert a function I have to ... . and at other I just got an ERROR. I

Comment: Are your all data in the format you've posted?

Comment: yes, they all are

Answer (score 4):

With a string in cell **A1**, this formula:

```
 =DATEVALUE(TRIM(LEFT(A1,11)))
```

will give the date part. *(this works if the day is one digit or two digits, the month must be three characters)*  If you had data with full month names rather than abbreviations, we would get the date by looking for the 3<sup>rd</sup> space character:

```
=DATEVALUE(TRIM(LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(1),3)))))
```

For **VBA**, try the following User Defined Function *(UDF)*:

```
Public Function DateMaker(s As String) As Date
    Dim arr
    arr = Split(s, " ")
    DateMaker = CDate(arr(0) & " " & arr(1) & " " & arr(2))
End Function
```

with the proper formatting:

[image]

User Defined Functions (UDFs) are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the UDF will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the UDF:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the UDF from Excel:

```
 =DateMaker(A1)
```

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

and for specifics on UDFs, see:

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/WritingFunctionsInVBA.aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so I managed to do it... pretty manually :). I don't use excel so excuse my methods.

First, I've selected the rows that contained the data all 236 of them.
The data was like 22 Jul 2017 13:51 GMT.
So I went to DATA tab, convert text to columns. I've selected date as DMY but I don't think it mattered.
Then I had 3 columns of the date with one for day, one for month and one for year.
Next I had to go find and replace one by one (since a formula I tried didn't work) Jan replaced by 1, Feb replaced by 2, etc.

At the end, I had a date format, almost done.
So I only had to merge them 3 into once cell, with "/" as separator.
So I used this =E2&"/"&F2&"/"&G2 where E2 was day, F2 was month and G2 was year. After that I only dragged the cell down to the last one, and there you have it.
Now I probably have to format it as a date, and I can sort it.
Thanks for all your answers!
This is not the fastest nor the easiest way possible, but it did the job :)

Comment: Sorry to comment. This method is not reusable. Follow Gary's student answer above and make your life east